# How To Verify or Test If a Trigger was fired in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

We have a trigger in SQL Server that is supposed to be fired on DML SQL queries i.e. when a value for column in a table is updated.
Is there a way to verify that the trigger was actually fired ?
I am looking for a SQL query or a log file that keeps record of any triggers that were fired.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I guess you could try and check the transaction log file, but I find the easiest way is to simply add timestamps columns to tables being updated by triggers which is only set by the trigger (or maybe even insert into a debug table if in doubt that a trigger is running)

Comment: No, but odds are good that if you're asking this, the problem is that the trigger has been written assuming that `inserted` and/or `deleted` contain exactly one row, and that assumption is invalid so the trigger isn't operating correctly. Of course, you've not shown the code but it's my prediction.

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no such thing that I know of.

To test if a trigger fires you can add a PRINT statement to the trigger (e.g. "PRINT 'trigger fired!'"), then do something that should trigger the trigger. If you get the printed text in your messages-tab in management studio you know it fired.